# android international app name in titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium

i have followed this [link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Internationalization)

In TiApp.xml file i have

```
 <application android:debuggable="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
            android:label="@string/appname" android:name="appname">

            <!-- TI_APPLICATION -->
            <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
                android:label="@string/appname"
                android:name=".appname" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium" >
```

i also have

- i18n / ar /
- app.xml
- strings.xml

strings.xml have

```
<string name="appname">تطبيق</string>
```

now the application once run should take the name from strings.xml  but it is not doing that 
i am also switching the language to arabic

iphone version of the app works fine and takes it name from app.xml file but the android one does not takes it name from strings.xml file

Comment: i am running in 4 not in 2.2  so arabic should be supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some instructions given in [Internationalizing AppName](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Internationalization) . For android you have to add platform folder which contains android folder and language specific strings folders .Naming conventions for android and IOS folders is different .I changed keyboard language  to Arabic and followed your link for internationalizing appname

[image: Demo AppName]

your AndroidManifest.xml according to instrutions must be

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="Application"
        android:debuggable="false">

        <!-- TI_APPLICATION -->

        <activity android:name=".Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
```